# Python: how can I assign a function to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

I created a data quantity calculator. I want, that I input a number and the number is assign to a function. For example: inputChose your input 1 and I get the bit calculator. input("Choose your calculator") and then 1 is assign to the bit calculator

```
#Tebibyte Calculator
def tebi():
    x = int(input("Please enter number of tebibytes")))
    # y = Bit, z = Byte, a = Kibibytes, b = Mebibytes, c = Gibibytes
    y = x * 8,796*10**9
    z = x * 1.1*10**12
    a = x * 1.1*10**9
    b = x * 1,1049*10**9
    c = x * 1024
    # Output of invoices
    print(
        x, "Tebibyte :", y, "Bits \n",
        x, "Tebibyte :", z, "Byte\n",
        x, "Tebibyte :", a, "Kibibyte\n",
        x, "Tebibyte :", b, "Mebibyte\n",
        x, "Tebibyte :", c, "Gibibytes"
    )
input("Please choose your converter\n"
    "1 - Input in Bit\n"
    "2 - Input in Byte\n"
    "3 - Input in Kibibyte\n"
    "4 - Input in Mebibyte\n"
    "5 - Input in Gibibyte\n"
    "6 - Input in Tebibyte\n"
    "0 - Exit"
    )
6 = tebi()
```

Comment: You can't create a variable with only integer in its name.

Comment: You can however have a list of lambdas/`def`'d functions. Are you just wanting to get a function using a number? And what functions are you referring to?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. The question is not clear, but you can [edit] to clarify. Maybe include some example input and output. See [ask] for more tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is to take an input and call a function. You can do this by modifying your input statement a little and using a dictionary.

E.g.

```
# your input is 6 in your example
myInput = input(...)
# dictionary of functions
myFunctions = {6: tebi, 7: someOtherFun}
```

Essentially then the input acts as a key for the dictionary to obtain the function you want as

```
chosenFunc = myFunctions[myInput]
chosenFunc()  # call my function
```